# Api.ai context limit(10 contexts per intent)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am adding output context in my intent in Api.ai but after creating the 10th output context in intent,api.ai is giving me this "The number of output contexts per intent has reached the limit of 10" and I am unable to further add output context in that intent.Is there a way to increase the context per intent limit.I need to create more than 15-20 output contexts in my api.ai agent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need that many, but there is no way of adding more than 10 contexts at this time

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow.com has now come up with Standard & Enterprise editions. As mentioned in this snap, you should contact support@dialogflow.com to apply for higher quotas. You may need to pay for this.

[image]